# NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel: How can I preselect a file before the dialog opens?

Tags: cocoa, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

When I present a `NSOpenPanel` to the user I'd like it to have a file that the user opened earlier already selected from the start.

There is `[NSSavePanel setDirectoryURL:(NSURL*)` to preselect a directory, but I can't find an API to select the initial file.

There use to be:

```
- (NSInteger)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path file:(NSString *)filename
```

This call is exactly what I need. The docs say:

> *Specifies a particular file in path that is selected when the Save
>   panel is presented to a user. When nil, no file is initially selected.*

But unfortunately that method was deprecated in 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Do these NSSavePanel methods

```
- (void)setDirectoryURL:(NSURL *)url
- (void)setNameFieldStringValue:(NSString *)value
```

not do what you want?

NSOpenPanel is a subclass of NSSavePanel so it has these methods also.

Comment: No, `setNameFieldStringValue:` does not work for me (10.7 SDK). The panel opens in the correct directory (`setDirectoryURL:`) works, but does not select the file. However, the deprecated method works as expected: `[panel runModalForDirectory:dir file:file]`...

Comment: I tried to use a `NSSavePanel` and here `setNameFieldStringValue:` works. An open panel does not have a name field, only a selection list. Is that the problem?